# c++ memory allocation in a for loop in vector<char> in a for loop

Tags: c++, memory, for-loop, vector, allocation

I have a memory allocation problem in the following function when reallocating the vector `chunk` object, what am I missing and what could be the possible solution?

```
    public:
    void send_FILE(std::string file_id, std::string file_path)
    {

        char* fid = moqane::number2string::To_CharArray(file_id);
        int fid_length = moqane::number2string::CharArray_Length(fid);
        const int step = packet_->BUFFER_SIZE;
        long total_length = boost::filesystem::file_size(file_path);


        for (int x = 0; x < total_length; x += step)
        {
            if ((x + step) <= total_length)
            {
                std::vector<char> chunk = moqane::file::GetFileChunk(file_path, x, x+step);
                write_FILE_CHUNK(fid, fid_length, chunk);

            }
            else
            {
                std::vector<char> chunk = moqane::file::GetFileChunk(file_path, x, total_length);
                write_FILE_CHUNK(fid, fid_length, chunk );
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

This the moqane::GetFileChunk() function

```
 public:
    static std::vector<char> GetFileChunk(std::string file_path, int from_pos, int to_pos)
    {
        boost::filesystem::ifstream file;
        if (file)
        {
            file.open(file_path.c_str(),std::ios::in|ios::binary);
            file.seekg(from_pos,std::ios::beg);

            std::vector<char> buffer(to_pos - from_pos);
            file.read(&buffer[0], to_pos);



             return buffer;
        }


    }
```

Comment: what problem exactly?

Comment: Would help if you described the problem you're having in more detail

Comment: I think you should  at least include more info about your problem and what moqane::file::GetFileChunk does.

Comment: when debugging i got a stack error in `std::vector<char> chunk` in the for loop it was in the stack: `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::allocate(this....`

Comment: a segmentation fault to be more precise.

Comment: Without a description, I can only guess; but perhaps `write_FILE_CHUNK` stores a reference or pointer to the vector or its contents, and something else accesses it after the vector has been destroyed? That's the only reasonably likely memory problem I can see here.

Comment: moqane::file::GetFileChunk is a function I made to read a chunk from file given a starting and end position

Comment: Please post the source of moqane::file::GetFileChunk. It will give a better understanding as to what potentially is going wrong.

Comment: @MohamedTarek: Where does the segfault happen? Your debugger should show you the call stack, and let you examine the dodgy address it was trying to access.

Comment: I have edited the code to include the moqane::file::GetFileChunk function, and the segmentation fault happened in the 2nd loop of `chunk` vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file.read(&buffer[0], to_pos);
```

should be

```
file.read(&buffer[0], to_pos - from_pos);
```

Otherwise, if `from_pos` isn't zero, you'll write beyond the end of `buffer`, causing dreadful calamities.